# Force inlining of policy functions

Tags: sql, postgresql

As a followup to [Query is slow with SECURITY INVOKER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75993031):

I have the following policy for one of my tables:

```
CREATE FUNCTION is_auth_member_of_org(_organization_id uuid)
  RETURNS boolean
  LANGUAGE sql
  SECURITY DEFINER
  AS $function$
    SELECT EXISTS (
      SELECT 1
      FROM public.roles
      WHERE user_id = auth.uid()
      AND organization_id = _organization_id
    )
  $function$;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION is_auth_in_org_of_alias(_device_id UUID)
  RETURNS BOOLEAN
  SECURITY DEFINER
  LANGUAGE plpgsql
  AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN is_auth_member_of_org(
    (SELECT organization_id FROM public.devices WHERE alias = _device_id)
  );
END;
$$;

CREATE POLICY "Authenticated have full access to events table of devices in the orgs they are members in"
  ON events
  FOR ALL
  TO authenticated
  USING (public.is_auth_in_org_of_alias(device_id))
  WITH CHECK (public.is_auth_in_org_of_alias(device_id));
```

Even a simple `select *` on that table is extremely slow, as every line is checked against the policy.

After replacing the policy with an inlined one (see below), things got significantly faster.

```
CREATE POLICY "Authenticated have full access to events table of devices in the orgs they are members in"
ON events
FOR ALL
TO authenticated
USING (
  EXISTS(
    SELECT from public.roles r
    JOIN public.device d using (organization_id)
    WHERE r.user_id = auth.uid()
      AND d.alias = events.device_id
  )
);
```

Why can't Posgresql do the inlining itself? Is there a way to force it to do the inlining, so I can continue using the functions?

Comment: [Inlining of SQL functions](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Inlining_of_SQL_functions#Inlining_conditions_for_scalar_functions) "*A scalar function call will be inlined if all of the following conditions are met  ... the function is not SECURITY DEFINER*"

Comment: So I guess that means that I can not use a nice abstraction like functions for RLS policies.